# Entry point for Java applications: main(), init(), or run()?

Tags: java, jvm

So far I've been using `public void run() {}` methods to execute my code in Java. When/why might one want to use `main()` or `init()` instead of `run()`?

Comment: Are you using a GUI tool, that builds a bunch of skeleton code for you, and into which you drop your run method?

Answer (score 80, accepted):

This is a peculiar question because it's not supposed to be a matter of choice.

When you launch the JVM, you specify a class to run, and it is the `main()` of this class where your program starts.

By `init()`, I assume you mean the JApplet method. When an applet is launched in the browser, the `init()` method of the specified applet is executed as the first order of business.

By `run()`, I assume you mean the method of Runnable. This is the method invoked when a new thread is started.

- main: program start
- init: applet start
- run: thread start

If Eclipse is running your `run()` method even though you have no `main()`, then it is doing something peculiar and non-standard, but not infeasible. Perhaps you should post a sample class that you've been running this way.

Comment: Ha ha ha, OK: I am importing files from libraries that I can't read. So probably there is a Runnable being created somewhere, and then my run() methods are running runables. This was great, thanks!

Answer (score 21):

The `main` method is the entry point of a Java application.

Specifically、when the Java Virtual Machine is told to run an application by specifying its class (by using the `java` application launcher), it will look for the `main` method with the signature of `public static void main(String[])`.

From Sun's [`java` command page](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/tooldocs/windows/java.html):

> The **java** tool launches a Java application. It does this by starting
>   a Java runtime environment, loading a specified class, and invoking that
>   class's **main** method.
>
> The method must be declared public and static, it must not return any
>   value, and it must accept a `String` array as a parameter. The method
>   declaration must look like the following:
>
> ```
> public static void main(String args[])
> ```

For additional resources on how an Java application is executed, please refer to the following sources:

1. [Chapter 12: Execution](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/third_edition/html/execution.html) from the [Java Language Specification, Third Edition](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/third_edition/html/j3TOC.html).
2. [Chapter 5: Linking, Loading, Initializing](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jvms/second_edition/html/ConstantPool.doc.html) from the [Java Virtual Machine Specifications, Second Edition](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jvms/second_edition/html/VMSpecTOC.doc.html).
3. [A Closer Look at the "Hello World" Application](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/getStarted/application/index.html) from the [Java Tutorials](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/index.html).

---

The `run` method is the entry point for a new [`Thread`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html) or an class implementing the [`Runnable`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Runnable.html) interface. It is not called by the Java Virutal Machine when it is started up by the `java` command.

As a `Thread` or `Runnable` itself cannot be run directly by the Java Virtual Machine, so it must be invoked by the `Thread.start()` method. This can be accomplished by instantiating a `Thread` and calling its `start` method in the `main` method of the application:

```
public class MyRunnable implements Runnable
{
    public void run()
    {
        System.out.println("Hello World!");
    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        new Thread(new MyRunnable()).start();
    }
}
```

For more information and an example of how to start a subclass of `Thread` or a class implementing `Runnable`, see [Defining and Starting a Thread](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/essential/concurrency/runthread.html) from the Java Tutorials.

---

The `init` method is the first method called in an [Applet](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/applet/Applet.html) or [JApplet](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/JApplet.html).

When an applet is loaded by the Java plugin of a browser or by an applet viewer, it will first call the `Applet.init` method. Any initializations that are required to use the applet should be executed here. After the `init` method is complete, the `start` method is called.

For more information about when the `init` method of an applet is called, please read about the lifecycle of an applet at The [Life Cycle of an Applet](https://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/deployment/applet/lifeCycle.html) from the Java Tutorials.

See also: [How to Make Applets](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/uiswing/components/applet.html) from the Java Tutorial.

Answer (score 3):

Java has a special static method:

```
public static void main(String[] args) { ... }
```

which is executed in a class when the class is started with a java command line:

```
$ java Class
```

would execute said method in the class "Class" if it existed.

```
public void run() { ... }
```

is required by the Runnable interface, or inherited from the Thread class when creating new threads.

Answer (score 2):

The `main()` method is the entry point for a Java application. `run()` is typically used for new threads or tasks.

Where have you been writing a `run()` method, what kind of application are you writing (e.g. Swing, AWT, console etc) and what's your development environment?

Comment: I'm working in Eclipse, and while I don't know what AWT or swing mean, I have certainly written console programs. All of my programs have so far only had 1 run() method and no main() methods.

Comment: Hmm... I've just tried in Eclipse, and I can't launch classes which just have a run() method. How are you running these programs?

Answer (score -2):

as a beginner, i import acm packages, and in this package, run() starts executing of a thread, init() initialize the Java Applet.

Comment: Before answering old questions, have a look whether somebody already posted your answer. Imho, you're not providing something new, compared with Jegschemesch's answer.