# Which is the first method called when Java executes a program?

Tags: java

I am learning core Java and I have one question, "Which is the first method called when the program is executed?"

Comment: The static initisalizer for the class which contains the main is called first, only if this is successful does the main() method get called.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In addition to aioobes answer

A usual way to start a simple java program is to execute java like this:

```
java com.example.MyClass
```

`com.example.MyClass` (or your fully qualified class name) **needs** to have a main method with exactly this signature:

```
public static void main(String[] args)
```

(you're only allowed to change the name of the parameter, like `arguments` instead of `args`). The virtual machine will try to load the named class and try to invoke this static method which will "start the Java program".

Answer (score 9):

That would be the `main` method.

It should be declared as

```
public static void main(String[] args)
```

- It needs to be `public`, since the JVM should have access to call the method.
- It needs to be `static`, as no objects are instantiated when the program starts
- It takes an array of `String`s as argument (coming from the command-line)

Some good links to have a look at:

- [The main Method (from the official Getting started trail)](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/getStarted/application/index.html#MAIN)
- [What is the main method](http://www.java-tips.org/java-se-tips/java.lang/what-is-the-main-method.html)
- [Entry point for Java applications: main(), init(), or run()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/261428/entry-point-for-java-applications-main-init-or-run)

---

Some people may recommend you to write

```
public static void main(String... args)
```

this is equivalent to `String[] args` *if* you're using a compiler of version 1.5 or later. (I would discourage this unless you're extensively calling your `main` method internally with a varying number of arguments.)

Others may suggest

```
public static void main(String args[])
```

This is also equivalent, but discouraged by the [Java Coding Convention](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/codeconv-138413.html).

Comment: you missed var arg version of main check my answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4194407/which-is-the-first-method-called-when-java-executes-a-program/4194425#4194425

Answer (score 5):

It's usually main. But in this program, it's pain:

```
public class WhatThe {
    public static final int x = pain();
    public static int pain() {
        System.out.println("pain!");
        return 0;
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("main");
    }
}
```

As it is in this one:

```
public class WhatThe {
    static {
        pain();
    }
    public static void pain() {
        System.out.println("pain!");
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("main");
    }
}
```

This is unlikely to be useful knowledge, but it's something to be aware of.

Answer (score 4):

```
public static void main(String ar[])
```

Java programs start executing at the main method, which has the following method heading:

```
public static void main(String[] args)
public static void main(String... args) //java 1.5+
public static void main(String args[])
```

[Read more at docs](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/getStarted/application/index.html)

Comment: Note that `String...` only works on Java 1.5+. Also, the `String args[]` syntax is discouraged by the Java Coding Convention.

Answer (score 0):

The main method will be called first,control goes to main method first which has the method headings:
public static void main(String[] args) or
public static void main(String args[])