# Difference between init() and main() method in java

Tags: java, jakarta-ee

I want to know the difference between init and main method of java

Comment: They have different names.

Comment: What class is your init() method from? Please clarify your question. Are you referring to the public static void main(String[] args) method?

Comment: i think he means the servlet init(). Main methods you have in applications.

Comment: Here is the answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/261428/entry-point-for-java-applications-main-init-or-run

Answer (score 6):

The main method is used as an entry point for applications, the init method is used as an entry point for applets and servlets.

Answer (score 1):

`static void` `main` is usually the declaration for a method which allows an entry point for launching the Java file/application. however, `main` can also be used to name any random method.

while `init` is one of the many random names which can be selected for naming a method [satisfying the basic rules for naming methods]. typically, programmers, in Java or any other programming language, like to name a method `init` if there's some initialisation routine to be run.

Answer (score 0):

init method is used when servlets or applets is initialize while main method is used for entry point of program....

If there is first time request for servlet then first of all servlet's init method is called and also some properties may be initialize at that time
While when you start your application main is entry point for that .......means main is first process for your application