# Error when creating a Caesar Cipher Program in Java

Tags: java, runtime-error

I am trying to create a program that changes 'a' to 'd', 'b' to 'e', etc. I have written some code and keep getting this error message:

> Error: Main method not found in class ec1, please define the main method as:
>      public static void main(String[] args)
>   or a JavaFX application class must extend javafx.application.Application

Here is my code:

```
public class ec1 {
   private String ALPHABET = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabc";

   public String encrypt()
     {
         Scanner scan2 = new Scanner(System.in);
            System.out.println("Enter your message");
            String poop = scan2.toString();

            int key = 3;

            String code="";
           for(int i=0;i<poop.length();i++)
           {
                int a = ALPHABET.indexOf(poop.charAt(i));
                int keyVal = (key+a)%26;
                char replaceVal = this.ALPHABET.charAt(keyVal);
                code += replaceVal;
           }
           return code;
     }

     }
```

Comment: just read the error... there is teh solution for you: `public static void main(String[] args){encrypt()}`

Comment: That would be because you don't have a `main` method.

Comment: Think of it this way: how would you expect your `encrypt` method to be called? The program must begin somewhere; in Java, that is the `main` method.

Comment: @fmodos The method is not static, the class would have to be instantiated first.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

JVM searches for the main() method to start the execution. so the control starts from there, you need to add `main()` method to your class and call the `encrypt()` method inside it.

```
   public static void main (String[] args) 
    {
     ec1 obj=new ec1();
     String encrypted_value=obj.encrypt();
    }
```

Read [The Java Main Method](http://csis.pace.edu/~bergin/KarelJava2ed/ch2/javamain.html) and also [Entry point for Java applications: main(), init(), or run()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/261428/entry-point-for-java-applications-main-init-or-run)

Comment: ok where should I place that method? fairly new to coding only been a couple of months

Comment: @WonderphuL Inside your class `ec1` wrap it to the beginning or the end

Comment: I put in the main method you posted and now the code is being terminated after outputting the scanner. Also it says String encrypted_value=obj.encrypt(); is not being used